# Test to check if any content is there with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, shoulda

So you can have a test like this:

```
find(".blah").should have_content("blah blah")
```

But is there a way to just check if something is in blah?

```
find(".blah").should have_some_content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a Capybara::RSpecMatchers for what you want. However, you could use the underlying Capybara::Node::Matchers.

Try:

```
find(".blah").has_no_text?.should be_true
```

If you really want to use the Capybara::RSpecMatchers, you could use `have_content` with a regex that looks for any non-whitespace character.

```
find(".blah").should have_content(/[^\s]/)
```

Comment: The has_no_text? is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Capybara.

Instead of the style in question, I will write it like this

```
page.should have_css('.bar', text: 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would inspect the return value of `find(".blah")` and see what it is in the following two scenarios:

- You know it's there, and something is returned
- You know it's NOT there and something else (maybe `nil`?) is returned

Then writing the test just to confirm that, in your case, some elements with that class exist is easy. It's just a matter of knowing the difference between the return values of the `.find` method when there is and is not something found.